# How do you equip dual weapons via a hotkey in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm playing a rogue and have two daggers I'd like to be able to equip via hotkeys.  If I put a dagger each in hotkey 4 and 5 and I hit '4' then '5' it equips each into my main hand.  How do I get one into my main and one into my off-hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a macro to equip the weapons to a specific slot. You didn't provide the names of your daggers, so this is the best I can offer:

```
/equipslot 16 *name of main hand dagger*
/equipslot 17 *name of off hand dagger*
```

Source: [WoWpedia.org](http://www.wowpedia.org/Useful_macros_for_rogues)

You don't actually need to use both lines in a single macro -- you could have one macro to switch off-hand daggers, and another one to switch main-hand daggers, but switching them at the same times has the benefit of not resetting your swing timer twice (which swapping weapons does. No problems if you're swapping while not in combat)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz -- was there something wrong with WoWWiki?

Comment: I will add to this that the last time I tried (July 2010) the macro feature does not allow you to equip two weapons of the same name in this way. It will force one to the main hand, and will not equip the second to the off-hand.

Comment: @Kymully I don't know the exact syntax, but you should be able to equip via the item's position in your backpack, which can circumvent that case.

Comment: @Raven: WoWWiki's admins have forked off to WoWpedia for a number of reasons, not least of which being substantially less advertising. Given that the vast majority of the admin community has moved over, and given that WoWpedia is actually integrated directly into [Blizzards new WoW forums](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/1334974#blog), WoWpedia is much more likely to stay up to date going forward.

Comment: @Kymully The easiest way to handle working with multiple weapons of the same name is to use the in game Equipment Manager feature. Just make an item set including only the relevant weapons. Bag position macros are kind of a hassle.

Comment: @kymully uh oh, both my daggers are the same name :(

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an equip-manager especially one that is going you if you become weaponless due to wanting to swap an item not in your bags or leave you wish a fishing pole and so forth.

Remember that swapping weapons / off hands leaves you with timer resets, basically weaponless for a brief period of time.